# How do I use CASE WHEN in DataColumn.Expression?

Tags: c#, sql, expression, datacolumn

I have a table with 1 column: 'Status' I want to add in another column named 'Action', its value will be as follow:

```
If column Status = '0' Then Action = 'Start', 
If column Status = '1' Then Action = 'Ready', 
If column Status = '2' Then Action = 'Go',
```

How do I add a column with Expression like that?

I tried following but it doesn't work:

```
 myDataTable.Columns.Add("Action", "CASE (WHEN [Status] = '0') THEN "Start")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are mismatched, and you are missing the column type parameter to the Add method.

Also, expressions do not seem to support CASE statements.  Try a nested IIF instead:

Try this:

```
workTable.Columns.Add("Action", 
                      typeof(string), 
                      "IIF([Status] = '0', 'Start', IIF([Status] = '1', 'Ready', 'Go'))");
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx